# Selenium/Java - Cannot locate option with index

Tags: java, selenium

I am practicing selenium with practiceautomation.com site. I have problem with registration - my selector cannot locate option with index.

code:

```
Select yearSelector = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("years")));
            yearSelector.selectByIndex(2000);
```

And I got something like:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with index: 2000
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-NN5LV43', ip: '192.168.0.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

It is strange, because I use also

```
Select dateSelector = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("days")));
        dateSelector.selectByIndex(15);
```

And everything works fine and the day on the list is normally selected

Picture:
[Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANJUZ.png)
As you can see, years are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to select by index **2000** and errors says no option with index 2000. Maybe you want to select by value?

```
Select yearSelector = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("years")));
yearSelector.selectByValue("2000");
```

Comment: @Szewniak If this answer works for you, please consider accepting the answer, he will get the points. There is a hollow tic which is below the downvote arrow where you need to click, immediately after your click, it will turn into green.

Comment: I did it, sory for being late :<

Comment: @Szewniak you accept not my answer :))). Better to accept answer that works for you

Comment: @Amit no problem for me:))

Answer (score 2):

`public void selectByIndex(int index)`

The above method select the option at the given index. This is done by examining the "index" attribute of an element, and not merely by counting.If no matching option elements are found then NoSuchElementException is thrown

Check for index attribute in html with value as 2000 it should not be there so try with

```
selector.selectByIndex(1); // see first visible year is selected or not
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. selectByIndex didnt work, I used selectByValue as sers said ;)

Comment: It may not work because index attribute may not be present in your HTML. as stated in definition. Learning is also important.... if you know why selectByIndex() method is not working that means answer served its purpose... Thankyou.